# Table data extraction from a pdf file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a pdf file using python, I tried doing the same with camelot and tabula but the results weren't accurate enough. Is there any way to get the data present in the tables of the pdf?

Comment: This might help you
https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2017/02/16/data-mining-ocr-pdfs-using-pdftabextract-to-liberate-tabular-data-from-scanned-documents/

Comment: Could you bring your PDF here?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/). You can extract either text containing "pdf markdown" and than parse it with regular expressions for example:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

pdf_markdown = ""

try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass

data = my_table_parser(pdf_markdown)
```